# Socket.IO + Node.JS + HTTPS

Tags: node.js, сервер, ssl, https, socket.io

Замучился, сделал небольшой сервер на Node, начало такое:

```
 var https = require('https');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/******/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
    var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/******/cert.pem', 'utf8');
    var credentials = {
        key: privateKey,
        cert: certificate
    };
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
    httpsServer.listen(8443);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpsServer);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { *** }
```

При запуске сначала всё в порядке, :8443/socket.io/socket.io.js доступен, но как только дело доходит до рукопожатий, сервер крашится с ошибкой `nodejs: ../src/util-inl.h:196: TypeName* node::Unwrap(v8::Local<v8::Object>) [with TypeName = node::TLSWrap]: Assertion`(object->InternalFieldCount()) > (0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)`
Порты открыты, сертификаты в номре, нужные модули установлены. В чём подвох?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чём конкретно трабл я не очень понял, на другом сервере с такой же версией nodejs всё работало и так, но помогло обновление до последней стабильной версии.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
```